# Как сделать что бы кнопка нажималась один раз, а так же вывести доп поле с %

Tags: javascript

Помогите решить проблему, так как в js не шарю. 
Суть задачи такова. 
При нажатии на кнопку нужно что бы она стала не активной(нажать можно только 1 раз). 
Так же нужно вывести еще одно поле с рандомным значением (3% 4% 5%). 
Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Код html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>123</title>
    <script src="random.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center;">

<button onclick="generate()">Generate!</button>
    <div id="random" style="font-size: 25px; color: green; "></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function generate() {
    var pass = "";
    var strong = 5;
    var dic = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";

    for (var i = 0; i < strong; i++) 
    {
        pass += dic.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * dic.length));
    }
    document.getElementById('random').innerHTML = pass;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте передать `this` в функцию `generate`, а за то чтобы кнопка была недоступна отвечает атрибут `disabled`:

```js
function generate(el) {
  el.disabled = true;
  var pass = "";
  var strong = 5;
  var dic = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";

  for (var i = 0; i < strong; i++) {
    pass += dic.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * dic.length));
  }
  document.getElementById('random').innerHTML = pass;
  document.getElementById('random-percent').innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 3 + '%';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="generate(this)">Generate!</button>
<div id="random" style="font-size: 25px; color: green; "></div>
<div id="random-percent" style="font-size: 25px; color: green; "></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.currentTarget.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = Math.floor(3 + Math.random() * (3)) + "%";
});
```

```html
<button>Generate</button>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener);
Используйте `once: true`, чтобы выполнить обработчик один раз.

```js
function generate() {
  var pass = "";
  var strong = 5;
  var dic = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";

  for (var i = 0; i < strong; i++) {
    pass += dic.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * dic.length));
  }

  pass += "<br>";
  pass += Math.round(3 + Math.random() * 2) + "%";

  document.getElementById('random').innerHTML = pass;
  
  document.getElementById("btn").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", generate, {
  once: true
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>123</title>
  <script src="random.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center;">

  <button id="btn">Generate!</button>
  <div id="random" style="font-size: 25px; color: green; "></div>
</body>

</html>
```